# How to make custom toolbar menu visible for my android app?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have prepared the custom toolbar `toolbar.xml` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar1"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:background="#BCBCDD"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   app:logo="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now I have created a menu directory, and in that `toolbar_menu.xml` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:title="Share"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
    android:title="Settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
    android:title="Exit"/>
</menu>
```

Now I have included this `toolbar layout` in `my main activity. xml` with `<include/>` tag.
After all this implementation I have set the toolbar in `MainActivity.kt` which is as below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar1)) //Set the Action Bar -> toolbar

    val apiService : ApiService = ApiClient.getClient()
    coronaRepository =
        CoronaDetailsRepository(
            apiService
        )

    viewModel = getViewModel(1,1)
    viewModel.coronaDetails.observe(this, Observer {
        bindUI(it)
    })

    viewModel.networkState.observe(this, Observer {
        loader.visibility = if (it == NetworkState.LOADING) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    })

}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)   // Used Menu Inflater to inflate the layout
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.menu_share -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        R.id.menu_settings -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        R.id.menu_exit -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

My toolbar is appearing on the main screen when app runs but the menu is not visible. I am wondering that what is wrong going on in my code??

Comment: Have you tried adding this `app:showAsAction="always"` to every item in your menu?

Comment: Yes, but the item is not visible instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside onCreate

```
..
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar1))
..
```

Inside onCreateOptionsMenu

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Comment: '''my_toolbar''' is the id of include tag which I have included in the mainactivity.xml file.

Comment: Try removing it, because my_toolbar1 is still accessible via activity_main.

Comment: I have tried but no change occurred... also when I have put break point and debug the code on `override fun onCreateOptionsMenu`, the application doesnot break .. My meaning is that the `override fun` is not called on. However the menu is not visible on the toolbar.

Comment: Also, there is no need to put an id on the include tag since menu_toolbar already has an id.

Comment: I am getting blank toolbar without menu options. I have applied as per your comment. I have changed the color as well of the toolbar as i have noticed that color was the same but then also problem remains the same. I am finding the fault but i think implementation was correct or not??

Comment: I have directly put my `toolbar.xml` file in my `mainactivity.xml` instead of `include` tag. I have removed the `include` tag and I have applied `toolbar.xml` code directly and **it works**. But now I have to repeat code in all the activity where I want toolbar but its not a good practice as a developer. I want to work on `DRY` concept and for that I have to do toolbar file separately, that is what I am doing..??

Comment: Including the file should work fine.  If you use <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>, that should behave the same way as putting the toolbar xml tag inside the mainactivity.xml